# Query Rally's project owner

Tags: javascript, rally

I have been trying to query the project's owner with sth like:

```
queries.push({
   type:"Project",
   key:"project",
   fetch:"Owner",
   query:"(ObjectID = __PROJECT_OID__)"
});
```

but it's not working, and I found no advice on the Internet on how to do that
Can someone show me how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting your fetch:

```
     fetch: "Owner,UserName"
```

And then adjust your query:

```
     query: "(Owner.Username = \"user@company.com\")"
```

Which should give you Projects owned by user@company.com.

Comment: hi Mark, this solves the issue when I know exactly who the owner is. What if I don't know the owner?

Comment: In that situation, keep your query to filter on ObjectID - with the fetch including both the Owner object and the UserName attribute you'll then be able to pull the Owner information from the datastore.